# How to generate jar from java classes in target

Tags: java, maven

I want to generate a jar from Java classes I have in Target. I've prepared this profile in pom.xml maven:

```
        <profile>
        <id>my-jar</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>target/generated-sources/main/**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I run it this way:

```
mvn package -P my-jar
```

It generates jar file but without my java classes from target inside. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: yup, you instruct maven to only include some generated java source files - sure you want that?

Comment: I have java classes in target/generated-sources/main. I generated these classes before i run my-jar profile. I want to have jar with only my generated classes.

Comment: It does not make sense to put uncompiled Java classes into a JAR.

Comment: When ill have jar with my classes inside I want to use it as dependency in pom.xml and use them in my project.

Comment: If that project is compiled and package the resulting jar contains already the compiled classes from your `target` including the ones `target/generated-sources`... if you like to have the generated part and other separated make a separate module which contains only the generation ...

Answer (score 0):

In order to create JAR file with only your code then you can use below command without adding any extra plugin in pom.xml

```
mvn package
```

But if you want dependencies also to be part of your JAR file then you need to add assembly plugin in pom.xml and execute below command.

```
mvn package assembly:single
```

You can check steps in this tutorial for both commands: https://youtu.be/YwD9N9VYBCw?feature=shared

Comment: Please, do not post one youtube tutorial link. Put in your answer the steps for the commands.